# How to detect if atof or _wtof failes?

Tags: c++

How to detect if atof or _wtof failes to convert the string to double? But not by trying to check if the result is different form 0.0 because my input can be 0.0. Thanks!

Comment: You just discovered the reason why using the atoX functions is bad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use `atof`. Instead, use `strtod`, from `<cstdlib>`, and also check `errno` from `<cerrno>`:

```
// assume: "char * mystr" is a null-terminated string

char * e;
errno = 0;
double x = std::strtod(mystring, &e);

if (*e != '\0' ||  // error, we didn't consume the entire string
    errno != 0 )   // error, overflow or underflow
{
    // fail
}
```

The pointer `e` points one past the last consumed character. You can also check `e == mystr` to see if *any* characters got consumed.

There's also `std::wcstod` for working with `wchar_t`-strings, from `<cwstring>`.

In C++11 you also have `std::to_string`/`std::to_wstring`, from `<string>`, but I believe that throws an exception if the conversion fails, which may not be a desirable failure mode when dealing with external data.

Comment: @TerranceCohen: No. (But you may still wanto to check `errno` to catch over- and underflow.)

Answer (score 2):

Using `atof`, you can't. But since this is C++, I suggest you use a `std::stringstream` and check it with `operator !` after applying `operator >>` to a `double`.